# Shopify Template Author Information (shortcode?)

Tags: shopify, liquid, shortcode

I am new to Shopify, I need to create an Author Information Section in the Blog Posts where the user has the flexibility to enter and modify the content and display it, it should have also the ability to reuse it to the other blog page with the content inside.

Can we do it in shortcode? Can we do it without apps?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? The only solution I found is to hardcode the author sections into a snippet and use conditional logic based on a metafield but it's not an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Sections in Shopify to reuse the content on different pages. For your specific case, you can create an **author-box** section using

```
<section id={{section.id}}>
  <h3>{{section.settings.title}}</h3>
  
  {{section.settings.content}}
  
</section>
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Author Box",
    "settings": [
      {
       "type": "text",
       "id": "title",
       "label": "Title",
       "default": "About Author"
      },
      {
       "type": "richtext",
       "id": "content",
       "label": "Content"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

Then you can include this section in **article** template where you want this section to show using

```
{% section 'author-box'%}
```

[Custom Sections in Shopify](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/how-to-create-your-first-shopify-theme-section)

Comment: Thanks for this, but can I do it that way in the Blog posts tab? Like adding a box that users can allow to enter the details of Author Information?

Comment: Same as this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsaSE28jRsvLMPBtA3boM7GF-ztqIfwa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This won't make the content reusable, though... right? It will make the ability to put an author box somewhere, but you'll have to copy in the content each time. If you change the author's bio or the image they use... you'll have to change it for potentially 100s of blog posts. It's the OPPOSITE of DRY.

Comment: @Armstrongest Sections are reusable. If you change the author's bio or image, you would only have to change it once in the settings of this section. It would change for all blog posts automatically as they all use the same **article** template.